# Authorize.net payment via card reader

Tags: ios, credit-card, authorize.net

Im planning to integrate a card reader like the one below in my ios app which will work as a self service kiosk.

http://anywherecommerce.com/products/hardware/

In this case how does the payment flow work? From the reader to the app what information do we get when someone inserts a card? Does it complete the payment with a merchant or do we just get the card number and required info and we have to make an API call?

I already have a web based api which accepts as input credit card number etc and accepts payments. I'm using authorize.net for payments. Can I use the same API with a device like this?

Answer (score 0):

To accept in-person or card present transactions with Authorize.Net, use the inperson-sdk-ios available on github: [enter link description here](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/inperson-sdk-ios)